# Accordion effect on many tables and just the first and last element

Tags: jquery

I use this jQuery script :

```
  $(function() {
      $(".accordionjquery tr:not(.lineclic)").hide();
      $(".accordionjquery tr:first-child").show();
      $(".accordionjquery tr.lineclic").click(function(){
          $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle(100);
      }).eq(0).trigger('click');
  });
```

My html script :

```
<table class="accordionjquery">
  <tr class="lineclic">
    <th>First Table</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HIDE1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HIDE2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HIDE3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><%= pie_chart @chart_enc %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="accordionjquery">
  <tr class="lineclic">
    <th>Second Table</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HIDE1</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HIDE2</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>HIDE3</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><%= pie_chart @chart_enc %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There are many tables like these.

When my page has been loaded, I want every tables are hided, except the first tr (with lineclic class ) and the last with pie_chart.

Loaded page :

```
<table class="accordionjquery">
  <tr class="lineclic">
    <th>First Table</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><%= pie_chart @chart_enc %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="accordionjquery">
  <tr class="lineclic">
    <th>First Table</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><%= pie_chart @chart_enc %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And when I click on the first row, the other `tr`s appear !

`pie_chart` doesn't support the `resizing` because it doesn't reload itself.

You can try : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7KJY5/) (only the second table is hided)

Thank you !

**EDIT :**
Thank you `Stiger` (`trigger('click')` removed) to get every tables "closed" :

```
  $(function() {
      $(".accordionjquery tr:not(.lineclic)").hide();
      $(".accordionjquery tr:first-child").show();
      $(".accordionjquery tr.lineclic").click(function(){
          $(this).nextAll("tr").fadeToggle(100);
      }).eq(0);
  });
```

Now, How to show the `header and the last tr (with the rails script : pie_chart)` ?

Comment: if you remove `.trigger('click');`, two table just show the header. Is this what you want?

Comment: Ok, it works, every tables are "closed". No, Header and the last row (with the chart).